# Directory could not be found

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

I have recently started to get an error which states my directory can not be found I have tried a number of ways to solve this but have yet to find a solution.

The method should allow the user to select an image for their computer and add it to a folder called images inside the applications folder structure. The problem is that when using the File.copy(imageFilename, path); it throws the error. I have tried changing the path and you will see from the code snip it. It is even doing it when the program itself has passed the file path for the application and is still throwing me the error.

this is the method.

```
    private void btnImageUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog imageFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        imageFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        imageFile.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        imageFile.FilterIndex = 1;

        if (imageFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            if(imageFile.CheckFileExists)
            {
                string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                System.IO.File.Copy(imageFile.FileName, path);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using VS2013 and have included the using Microsoft.win32

Any further information needed please ask.

Thanks

Comment: DeanOC What did you edit? lol. Not a problem just a query ha

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to set OpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things need to be taken into consideration

```
private void btnImageUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog imageFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    imageFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    imageFile.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
    imageFile.FilterIndex = 1;

    if (imageFile.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        if(imageFile.CheckFileExists)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // You wont need it 
            System.IO.File.Copy(imageFile.FileName, path); // Copy Needs Source File Name and Destination File Name
        }
    }
}
```

`string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` You won need this because the default directory is your current directory where your program is running. 
Secondly 
`System.IO.File.Copy(imageFile.FileName, path);` Copy Needs Source File Name and Destination File Name so you just need to give the file name instead of path

so your updated code will be

```
private void btnImageUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog imageFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    imageFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    imageFile.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
    imageFile.FilterIndex = 1;

    if (imageFile.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        if(imageFile.CheckFileExists)
        {
            System.IO.File.Copy(imageFile.FileName, SomeName + ".jpg"); // SomeName Must change everytime like ID or something 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mohit 
I have solved the issue and the code was a basic code to help better understand the problem. I did not reliese that i dont need to do that however I am storing the selected image in a folder called Images (stored as part of the applications structure). I had hoped to use the path as a direction to the applications root or image folder directly but thanks for the info.

Comment: NP dear. It is fun resolving problems. You can just add `/images/` after path and your objective will be accomplished.

Comment: may be fun resolving them but its certainly not fun having them lol but a little side note. I know the path at the moment enters the bin\\debug but if i will to release this application would this still work in locating the images folder if it was to add a substring() to it and removing the bin\\debug?. Sorry i know this would be a separate question probably.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` actually points to the location of your executable file so now even if you release the application it would point to the same directory where your application executable exists. So if your image folder is inside Application Folder/Images then yes the same code will work

Comment: again Thanks for all the help this makes it a little easier to understand this.. Hard to think I am just about to start my honours year in software development as well.

Comment: Well good to know that I was helpful. You can upvote the answer to say thanks. :) Good luck ... Happy Coding!!

Comment: I will upvote this answer as well once I reach level 15 lol as both answers have answered my question and also broaden my knowledge of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's the problem, but the `File.Copy` method expects a source file name and a target file name, not a source file name and directory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx

So, to make this work, in your case you'd have to do something like the following (namespaces omitted):

```
File.Copy(imageFile.FileName, Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileName(imageFile.FileName));
```

Note that this will fail if the destination file exists, to overwrite it, you need to add an extra parameter to the `Copy` method (`true`).

EDIT:
Just a note, the `OpenFileDialog.CheckFileExists` does not return a value indicating if the selected file exists. Instead, it is a value indicating whether a file dialog displays a warning if the user specifies a file name that does not exist. So instead of checking this property after the dialog is closed, you should set it to `true` before you open it (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.checkfileexists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: hi vesan thanks for the quick response I personally didn't think it should have been a problem as i have done file uploads using other languages just not in c# and struggling to get over why it cant find the directory but will have a look and try adding the file name as well.

Comment: Np, I'm not sure if this will solve the problem, but the documentation states that the second parameter cannot be a directory, so it definitely needs to be changed in your code.

Comment: Thanks vesan that seemed to have worked. You are a star and i cant believe i had been so daft as to leave the file name out i just assumed it would have copied it over as its a file copy..